# How to execute token-based authentication using authenticate directive?

Tags: access-token, spray

I'm doing a token-based authentication, and I don't know how I am supposed to use `authenticate` directive in my route:

I'm getting `access_token` from a header.

```
post {
  headerValueByName("Access_Token") {
    access_token => {
      authenticate(??????){
        user => {
          ......
          ......
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I authenticate?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749. Either use a library or pass the task along, creating an OAuth2 server is no easy task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways how to do this, you can do this with some libraries like flavian proposed or do it yourself. Authenticate directives doesn't do much, i just "executes" standard authenticated mechanisms provided with Spray, you can read about them [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-routing/security-directives/authenticate/#authenticate). If this is not what you want or didn't understand how to do this, here is a small example.

Let's imagine the easiest case with token authentication, your token is saved in some storage and to authenticate a user you want just compare them. So we have this function:

```
def validate(token: AuthToken): Future[Authentication[User]] = {
  torage.findUserByToken(token) match { 
    case Some(user) => Right(user)
    case None => Left(AuthenticationFailedRejection(..))
  }
}
```

Where `Authentication[User]` is `Either[Rejection, T]`

If you take a look at `authenticate` directive, it's implemented with a [Magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/) and requires `AuthMagnet` and you have everything to get it, cause it has a conversion:

```
implicit def fromFutureAuth[T](auth: ⇒ Future[Authentication[T]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): AuthMagnet[T] =
    new AuthMagnet(onSuccess(auth))
```

So now you can use it:

```
post {
  headerValueByName("Access_Token") { access_token => {
    authenticate(validate(access_token)) { user => {
      ......
      ......
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, if you are looking for a good & secure way to store user account, check [stormpath](http://stormpath.com), it's quite easy to integrate them with Spray api.

Comment: Spray is obviously changing at a rather fast pace so maybe the above is no longer the latest or I'm doing it wrong (I am fairly new to Spray). So here is what works for me right now (Spray 1.3.1): I actually call `AuthMagnet.fromFutureAuth(f)` where f returns a `Future[Authentcation[User]]`. Would love to here if that is the way to go.